# .Mp4 custom Intent Filter from File Manager and Gallery

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

I'm having trouble writing the manifest.xml of my app. I want that when i try to open any .mp4 file the system asks me to open it with my app.

I was able to do it with this code:

```
<data android:pathPattern="*.mp4" android:scheme="file"/>
```

With that if i open any .mp4 file from a File Manager it's ok but i'm not able to do that from image gallery. 
There is a way to catch only the mp4 videos from both file managers and gallery?